# How to modify Disjktra algorithm to have at least X vertices or K edges in shortest path

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, data-structures, dijkstra

I have this Dijkstra algorithm although I want to modify it or is it possible to do it with another algorithm ?

I need to output the vertices of the shortest path, although I need to have at least 5 vertices (>=5 vertices) to the shortest path from start node to end node.

At the end of the code you'll see the Dijkstra algorithm so I would need to modify it so I could add a variable where I need to have at least X(5in my case) vertices.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
#include<list>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

typedef struct nodes {
        int dest;
        double cost;
}node;
class Graph{

    int n;


   list<node> *adjList;

   private:
      void showList(int src, list<node> lt) {
         list<node> :: iterator i;
         node tempNode;

         for(i = lt.begin(); i != lt.end(); i++) {
            tempNode = *i;
            cout << "(" << src << ")---("<<tempNode.dest << "|"<<tempNode.cost<<") ";
         }
         cout << endl;
      }
   public:
      Graph() {
         n = 0;
      }

      Graph(int nodeCount) {
         n = nodeCount;
         adjList = new list<node>[n];
      }

      void addEdge(int source, int dest, double cost) {
         node newNode;
         newNode.dest = dest;
         newNode.cost = cost;
         adjList[source].push_back(newNode);
      }

      void displayEdges() {
         for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
            list<node> tempList = adjList[i];
            showList(i, tempList);
         }
      }

      friend void dijkstra(Graph g, double *dist, int *prev, int start);
};

void dijkstra(Graph g, double *dist, int *prev, int start) {
   int n = g.n;

   for(int u = 0; u<n; u++) {
      dist[u] = 9999;   //set as infinity
      prev[u] = -1;    //undefined previous
   }

   dist[start] = 0;   //distance of start is 0
   set<int> S;       //create empty set S
   list<int> Q;

   for(int u = 0; u<n; u++) {
      Q.push_back(u);    //add each node into queue
   }

   while(!Q.empty()) {
      list<int> :: iterator i;
      i = min_element(Q.begin(), Q.end());
      int u = *i; //the minimum element from queue
      Q.remove(u);
      S.insert(u); //add u in the set
      list<node> :: iterator it;

      for(it = g.adjList[u].begin(); it != g.adjList[u].end();it++) {
         if((dist[u]+(it->cost)) < dist[it->dest]) { //relax (u,v)
            dist[it->dest] = (dist[u]+(it->cost));
            prev[it->dest] = u;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Is returning to the same vertex allowed?

Comment: Returning same vertex is not allowed sorry didn't mention

Comment: @ybungalobill or is it possible to do it with something else then dijsktra ?

Comment: So for the graph `V = { 0, 1 }, E = { (0,1), (1,0) }` there is no solution?

Comment: `list<node> *adjList;` -- Off-topic, but why not simply use `std::vector<list<node>> adjList;`?  Then there is no need for `n`, and no need for dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: I suspect that there’s no general way to do this efficiently. If you generalize this to say “give me the shortest path that goes through at least k nodes,” then you run the risk of turning your problem into the Hamiltonian path problem, which is NP-hard. In other words, I suspect that you may have to do some brute forcing somewhere in here.

Answer (score 0):

Disjktra algorithm works with status, normally the status is only the node as you use in your code, but can be modified for anothers use cases as this. You use dist[n] representing distance to reach node n, but you can modify it as dist[n][m] to represent distance to reach node n with exactly m nodes in path. The first problem that you can see is that if the max number of nodes >= 10^5 by example, you can't represent it in a matrix. So, the first optimization is use m=5, where for 1 <= m <= 4 represent exactly m nodes in path, but m = 5 is at least 5 nodes in path, more is not interesting for the problem.

```
void dijkstra(Graph g, double **dist, pair<int, int> **prev, int start) {
   int n = g.n;

   for(int u = 0; u<n; u++) {
       for(int v = 1; v <= 5; v++) {
          dist[u][v] = 9999999;   //set as infinity
          prev[u][v] = -1;    //undefined previous
      }
   }

   dist[start][1] = 0;   //distance of start is 0
   priority_queue<pair<double, pair<int, int> > > Q;
   
   Q.push(make_pair(0, make_pair(start, 1)));

   while(!Q.empty()) {
      pair<double, pair<int, int> > > top = Q.top(), Q.pop();
      u = top.second.firt;
      v = top.second.second;
      for(it = g.adjList[u].begin(); it != g.adjList[u].end();it++) {
          int w = (v == 5)? v : v + 1;
         if((dist[u][v]+(it->cost)) < dist[it->dest][w]) { //relax (u,v)
            dist[it->dest][w] = (dist[u][v]+(it->cost));
            prev[it->dest][w] = make_pair(u, v);
            Q.push(make_pair(-dist[it->dest][w], make_pair(it->dest, w))); // negative distance to reverse priority queue order
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I did some modifications, as use a priority_queue, I think that is a simple solution for same problem.

**PD: Maybe I wrote some mistakes, I haven't a compiler now to test. Sorry my english mistakes.**